# How many solutions to a boolean linear system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, matrix-equations

Let's suppose I have a matrix $A$ that is only composed of $0$'s and $1$'s. It has $k$ rows and $n$ columns where $n < k$. I want to find the number of solutions such that $Ax = b$ where the entries of $x$ are only zeroes and ones. And, $b$ is the all ones vector. All the algebra is over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Someone in a paper recently claimed that the number of solutions is divisible by $2^{k-n}$ but I cannot see why this is the case. Any help would be great.

Comment: The result would be more plausible if you had $n$ rows and $k$ columns. I think you can simply solve the system by Gaussian elimination. This leaves you at least $k-n$ free variables.

Comment: Does Gaussian Elimination always guarantee that the number of free variables is k-n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be the number of **rows** and $k$ be the number of **columns**. The rank $r$ of the system satisfies $r\le \min(n,k)$. The system can be reduced to row echelon form by Gaussian elimination. The number of free variables is $k−r$, which is necessarily larger than $k−n$. So if the system has a solution, it has exactly $2^{k−r}$ solutions (a multiple of $2^{k-n}$) obtained by giving the free variables all the possible boolean values, but it may also be unsolvable, as the system
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&1&0\\
1&1&0&0
\end{bmatrix} x =
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1\\1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Observe that if the system is unsolvable, it has 0 solutions, which is also a multiple of $2^{k-n}$. So the result is true in general.